Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) is not working properly, does not give the correct path to the selected folder
I am trying to write a program that allows you to save a sheet in a workbook to a folder of your choosing.
The issue is that when you run the macro and select the folder you want to save the sheet too, if you click OK it saves outside of the selected folder and when you press cancel it saves inside the selected folder.
The idea that im trying to go for is when I press OK it saves inside the selected folder and when I press cancel it cancels.
Any help is appreciated.
Sub CopySheetAsNewWorkbookWithPickingFileLocation()
Dim theNewWorkbook As Workbook
Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
Dim newFileName As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Dim GetFolder As String

'Picking a folder to save to
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

NextCode: sItem = GetFolder Set fldr = Nothing

'Make new file name = sheet name
newFileName = ActiveSheet.Name

'currentWorkbook is the source workbook, create a new workbook referencing to it with theNewWorkbook
Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set theNewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

'do the copy (it's better to check if there is already a 'Worksheet 1' in the new workbook. It it exists delete it or rename it
currentWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy before:=theNewWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Remove default sheets in order to have only the copied sheet inside the new workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim i As Integer
For i = theNewWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1
    theNewWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Save File
saveLocation = GetFolder
theNewWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=61
theNewWorkbook.Close

End Sub


Edited and marked changes in your code:
Sub CopySheetAsNewWorkbookWithPickingFileLocation()
Dim theNewWorkbook As Workbook
Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
Dim newFileName As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Dim GetFolder As String

'Picking a folder to save to
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'GoTo NextCode  if not selected quit the code.
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

'NextCode: sItem = GetFolder Set fldr = Nothing not necessary to remove variable, and define another.

'Make new file name = sheet name
newFileName = ActiveSheet.Name

'currentWorkbook is the source workbook, create a new workbook referencing to it with theNewWorkbook
Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set theNewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

'do the copy (it's better to check if there is already a 'Worksheet 1' in the new workbook. It it exists delete it or rename it
currentWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy before:=theNewWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Remove default sheets in order to have only the copied sheet inside the new workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim i As Integer
For i = theNewWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1
    theNewWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Save File
'saveLocation = GetFolder  not necessary a new variable
'theNewWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=GetFolder & "\" & newFileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=61 'define the full path of the target file.
theNewWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sItem & "\" & newFileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=61 'define the full path of the target file.
theNewWorkbook.Close

End Sub


Thank you for your help. I tried this and it got me past the error I was getting before, but it doesnt like "theNewRokbook.SaveAs Filename..." line but even after changing it to something it did like it would save outside the selected folder.

One correction was left when copied the code. Sorry. I edited the code.

That completely fixed it. It does not give an error anymore and saves to the correct folder. Thank you, I will try to understand why my code wasn't working by comparing it to yours.

Copy Sheet to New File
Sub CopySheetToNewFile()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const NO_ACTIVE_SHEET As String = "No active sheet!"
    Const FILE_DIALOG_TITLE As String = "Select a Folder" ' "Browse" (default)
    Const FILE_FIALOG_CANCEL As String = "Dialog canceled!"
    Const NEW_FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsx"
    Const NEW_FILE_FORMAT As Long = xlOpenXMLStrictWorkbook ' 61
    'Const NEW_FILE_FORMAT As Long = xlOpenXMLWorkbook ' 51 (default .xlsx)
    
    ' Reference the active (old) sheet...
    Dim ows As Object: Set ows = ActiveSheet
    If ows Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox NO_ACTIVE_SHEET, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' ... and its workbook.
    Dim owb As Workbook: Set owb = ows.Parent
        
    ' Build the initial (old) file path.
    Dim oPath As String: oPath = owb.Path
    If Len(oPath) = 0 Then oPath = CurDir
    oPath = oPath & Application.PathSeparator
    
    ' Let the user select the new folder path.
    Dim nPath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = oPath
        .Title = FILE_DIALOG_TITLE
        '.AllowMultiSelect = False ' 'True' doesn't work anyway for folders
        If .Show Then nPath = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    End With
    If Len(nPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox FILE_FIALOG_CANCEL, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Build the new file path.
    Dim oName As String: oName = ows.Name
    Dim NewFilePath As String: NewFilePath = nPath & oName & NEW_FILE_EXTENSION
    
    ' Copy the active sheet to a new workbook.
    ows.Copy
    
    ' Save and close the new workbook.
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
            .SaveAs Filename:=NewFilePath, FileFormat:=NEW_FILE_FORMAT
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False ' just got saved
    End With

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Sheet """ & oName & """ copied to new file.", vbInformation

End Sub


This worked great thank you. I am unsure what went wrong with my program but I will try to understand how you did it and see how I can avoid this error in the future.

Here is another approach :
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

Dim Path As String
Dim FileName As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    With fPth
        '.InitialFileName = Path & FileName
        .Title = "Save your File"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
            If .Show <> 0 Then
                ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            End If
    End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub


This was interesting as well although it didnt save one specific sheet but instead saved the entire file again, almost like clicking saveas. I am also trying to have it automatically chose a name based on the sheet name but I will experiment and see if I can get it to do that. But interesting none the less.

Ive edited the macro to save the active sheet only :
Sub CopySheetAsNewWorkbookWithPickingFileLocation()
Dim theNewWorkbook As Workbook
Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
Dim newFileName As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim saveLocation As String

' Picking a folder to save to
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub ' User canceled
    saveLocation = .SelectedItems(1) ' Selected folder path
End With
Set fldr = Nothing

' Make new file name = active sheet name
newFileName = ActiveSheet.Name

' Reference the current workbook and create a new workbook
Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set theNewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

' Copy the active sheet to the new workbook
currentWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=theNewWorkbook.Sheets(1)

' Remove default sheets in the new workbook, leaving only the copied sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim i As Integer
For i = theNewWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1
    theNewWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Save the new workbook in the selected folder with the sheet name as the file name
theNewWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=saveLocation & "\" & newFileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51

' Close the new workbook
theNewWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
